# react using jquery to slideToggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm trying to learn some React by making a menu with collapsable items. I'm using jQuery for its slideToggle function but I cant get it to work right.

the relevant part of the react code is this:

```
var CollapsableMenuItem = React.createClass({
    toggleDescription: function(el) {
        $(el).slideToggle();
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <li>
                <label className='title' 
                       onClick={this.toggleDescription.bind(this)}>
                    {this.props.item.title}
                </label>
                <div className='description'>
                    <label>
                        {this.props.item.body}
                    </label>
                </div>
            </li>
        );
    }
});
```

althought I'm currently trying to slide toggle "this", that will need to change in the future to

```
$(el).parent().find('.description').slideToggle();
```

because that's the actual element that needs to slide toggle

Whats the correct way of binding "this [element]" so jQuery can do its slideToggling on it?

I'm currently working out of [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/13028/), theres some other stuff in there you can ignore. The relevant code is at the bottom of the javascript section

a second question that comes to mind: is it bad practice to use the jQuery.ready function to bind click events etc... with react?

theoretically I can bundle a jquery file with each component file with its event handlers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The context of `this` in React isn't the element, it's the React component. jQuery doesn't understand how to use it as a selector.

You'll need to get a reference to the element you want to control with jQuery.

```
makeTogglable: function(element) {
  $element = $(element);

  this.toggle = function() {
    $element.slideToggle();
  };
},
render: function() {
  return (
    <li>
      <label onClick={this.toggle}></label>
      <div ref={this.makeTogglable}></div>
    </li>
  );
}
```

The [ref prop](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-callback-attribute) takes a callback, which will run when the component is mounted. The DOM element will be passed to the callback, so that you can work with it directly.

In this case, we use it to create and expose a new `this.toggle` method, which calls `.slideToggle` on the element.

Finally, we pass the new `this.toggle` method to the `onClick` handler for the element that we want to trigger the toggle. In this case it's the `<div>`.

Comment: thank you for the help! (are you guys hiring by any chance :) ?)

Comment: actually its not working, heres the fiddle with the updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/13031/

Comment: Make sure that you're using the most up to date version of React. I think jsfiddle uses an old one by default — and yeah, we are hiring. Reach out to me at dan@astraldynamics.co.uk if you are interested.