# How to use slideToggle function in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, toggle, slidetoggle

I am trying to convert this javascript function as is into react language.

```
$("#compare-btn").click(function(){
        $(".compare-show").slideToggle("slow");
    });
```

All I want to to do is to make a div slide into the page and stick a the bottom once I click on my "compare" button. Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implement a SlideToggle Functionality with React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48692961/implement-a-slidetoggle-functionality-with-react-js)

Comment: I have already checked this solution, but did not work for my case..

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/q/33979921/9516173

Comment: Could you please explain how to go from javascript to react on the following piece of code? I am new to it and I'm having difficulties playing around with some basic jquery. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your example in `React` should be:

```
import React from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';

class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.compareShow = React.createRef();
    this.slideToggle = this.slideToggle.bind(this);
  }

  slideToggle() {
    $(this.refs.compareShow.current).slideToggle();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <button onClick={this.slideToggle}>Toggle</button>
        <div ref={this.compareShow} />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```